# Skip internal filtering with React Bootstrap AsyncTypeahead?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-typeahead

I'm using `AsyncTypeahead` to query a GraphQL backend, and everything is working except one small visual glitch. The non-async version is designed to filter a fixed list of options in a dropdown menu as the user types. But with the async version, the backend query does the filtering so I don't need filtering on the frontend.

The problem is that the displayed menu is filtered and rerendered after sending the query but before the new results have come back. This causes an unnecessary and misleading UI update while waiting for the results.

For example, say you are searching for grocery items. The user types "ba" and sees

- baking powder
- bananas
- granola bars

They change their mind, delete "ba" and type "s", and a new query is sent. But before the results come back, the UI filters the existing list (items containing "ba") to items containing "s" and displays

- bananas
- granola bars

Once the full results come back, the UI updates again to show everything containing "s".

- bananas
- granola bars
- shampoo
- shaving cream

How can I eliminate that flash by having the UI update *only* when new results (called `options` in the component) are provided by the async query?